# vim syntax file, how to mark everything after the word END as a comment?

Tags: regex, vim

i am writing a vim syntax file and would like to highlight everything after (but not including) the word END until the end of the file as a comment. thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`:help :syn-region`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-region) starting *after* the `END` (so that the keyword itself is not highlighted; if you instead want a different highlighting for the keyword use `matchgroup=...` and drop the `\zs`), and ending with the special [`:help /\%$`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25%24) regexp atom.

```
:syntax region myEndComment start="\<END\>\zs" end="\%$"
:highlight def link myEndComment Comment
```

Comment: thank you, i got your answer to work now! the problem was that i had the keyword END declared elsewhere.

Comment: Glad I could help. With syntax items, it's important that each element is only matched by one rule (and the assertion with `\zs` already counts as "matching"); else, it will be ignored.